# Xcode: model adding entities

Tags: mongodb, core-data, ios7, xcode5, mmrecord

I am experimenting with API that returns some fields with underscore like _id. I am not able to map this field in the -xcdatamodel. The attribute must begin with letter.

I've also tried to map this field as "id" and provide in the "User Info" session a Key/Value like id : _id but without success.

Do you have a solution for this problem? As i know there are many APIs that have fields with underscore.

Other non underscore fields are mapped without problems.

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_avRateDelay": 5,
    "_avRateRecommend": 5,
    "_avRateStaff": 5,
    "_id": "530f733df222bf594b190e0a10",
    "_reviews": 1,
    "active": 1,
    "address": {
        "city": "Little Rock",
        "country": "USA",
        "other": "",
        "state": "AZ",
        "street": "2701 E Roosevelt Rd",
        "zip": "72206"
    },
    "location": {
        "lat": 34.721175,
        "lng": -92.24168600000002
    },
    "name": "Certainteed 69"
}
```

Comment: do you found any solution?

Comment: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMRecord  
  
 -> Look inside Section : Alternate Property Names ; 

This is how to handle fields like this!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `id` or `_id` in Objective-C.  `id` is a reserved word.  Since many servers like to use that I recommend that you write mapping code so that it is mapped from the server `id` to something like `identifier`.

Since you need to write code to parse the fields anyway there is no hardship to look for that key and change it.  You can even store the mapping in the `NSEntityDescription` and set up code to look for other mappings and change them.  That way you can change other server styled values like `created_at` to their Objective-C counterparts like `createdAt`.

The key/values are editable directly in the model editor and then accessible via the `-entity` property on the `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: I am using MMRecord framework to automatically create and populate the objects returned from API. No need to map manually.

Comment: I would suggest adding that to your question in the future so that people don't waste their valuable time.